How to install PowerPoint Add-ins programmatically using installer
I have created 3 Add-ins for PowerPoint and I am able to install it in PowerPoint manually from the developer tool of PowerPoint. But I want to add it automatically using some setup like the .msi file. I am able to create MSI files using Visual Studio which installs addins into the system but after installation, it does not come into PowerPoint automatically. Our requirement is to add it automatically once installation completes. any hint to solve this issue, please suggest.

